# How can i load balance on two eureka server on two different Machines?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am using Spring Boot and Eureka server for achieving scalability. I have two servers both contain one eureka server and multiple eureka clients.
I want to load balance the API calls b/w clients on one server to another server. lets if A wants to connect to B and B is not available on the local eureka than the eureka should check the client availability on peer eureka server and redirect if available.
I tried making both eureka servers peer of one another here is my configuration
But it is not checking availability on peer eureka server

```
spring.application.name=dfs-eureka-server
eureka.instance.hostname=192.168.3.63
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://192.168.3.0:9080/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.49
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=true
eureka.dashboard.path=/eurekaweb
```

second eureka server

```
spring.application.name=dfs-eureka-server
eureka.instance.hostname=192.168.3.0
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://192.168.3.63:9080/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.49
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=true
eureka.dashboard.path=/eurekaweb
```

eureka dashboard

[dashboard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvAqQ.png)

[dashboard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUhwV.png)

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep the below properties common in both the eureka servers and verify.

- eureka.instance.appname=eureka-cluster
- eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
- eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true